# Refresh ListView with custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter, onscrolllistener

I'm using `ListView` which is populated by custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`. Data is fetched from external server with  `AsyncTask` and onPostExecute method of `AsyncTask` calls a method on `ListActivity` that sets adapter to display data

`ListView` also implements `OnScrollListener` to fetch data on scroll and add to bottom.

I've an `ActionBar` (`Toolbar`) with custom view which contains `EditText` fields and `Button` on click of which, again, same `AsyncTask` is called to fetch new data with query values passed from `Toolbar`.

Problem is, when button on toolbar is clicked I want the `ListView` to be populated with entirely new data replacing the old values but instead new data is appended at the bottom of list ( as if `OnClickListener` is called).

I checked [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240144/refresh-listview-with-baseadapter), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193090/notifydatasetchange-does-not-refresh-listview-with-custom-adapter) but none seem to help

And of course main strike would be to use `NotifyDataSetChange` and I'm using that too but not worth it.

My method to set adapter

```
public void setBusinesses(ArrayList<BusinessListData> businesses) {

    imgFetcher = new BusinessListIconTask(this);
    layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    if (this.businesses == null || adapter == null) {
        this.businesses = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new BusinessListDataAdapter(this, imgFetcher,
                layoutInflator, this.businesses);
        businessList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    this.businesses.addAll(businesses);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    /* Activates when scrolling to bottom of list */
    businessList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        public int currentScrollState;
        public int currentFirstVisibleItem;
        public int currentVisibleItemCount;
        public int totalItemCount;
        public int lastItem;
        boolean isLoading = false;

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
            this.isScrollCompleted();

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            this.totalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            this.lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        }

        private void isScrollCompleted() {
            if (this.lastItem == this.totalItemCount) {
                /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
                if (!isLoading) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    getScrollData(metroTxt, metroLoc, metroId);
                }
            } else {
                businessList.removeFooterView(footerView);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

setting custom toolbar with search fields

```
void showCustomView(String metroTxt, String metroLoc, String metroId) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    if (mCustomView == null)
        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    mToolbar.removeView(mCustomView);
    mToolbar.addView(mCustomView);
    Log.d("I'm inside custom view", "txt" + metroTxt);
    abKeyword = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.ab_keyword);
    abLocation = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.ab_location);
    ab_search = (Button) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.ab_search);
    abKeyword.append(metroTxt);

    abLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ab_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    abKeyword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (hasFocus || !abKeyword.getText().toString().isEmpty() || !abLocation.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                abLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ab_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                abLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ab_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    abKeyword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            String newText = s.toString();

            BusinessInfoSuggestionTask autocompleteTask = new BusinessInfoSuggestionTask(BusinessResultListActivity.this);
            String acType = "keyword";

            if (s.length() >= 1) {
                abLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ab_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                autocompleteTask.execute(newText, acType, cActivity);

            } else {
                abLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ab_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

    });
    ab_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            String abKey = abKeyword.getText().toString();
            String abLoc = abLocation.getText().toString();
            String abId = "";
            getBusinesses(abKey, abLoc, abId);
            Log.d("I'm clicked", "button on toolbar clicked");
        }
    });

}
```

Methods to fetch data from server

```
/* Get Businesses data from server */
private void getBusinesses(String metroTxt, String metroLoc, String metroId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String first = "first";
    BusinessListApiTask spTask = new BusinessListApiTask(
            BusinessResultListActivity.this);
    try {
        spTask.execute(metroTxt, metroLoc, metroId, first);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        spTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

/* Fetch more data on scroll */
private void getScrollData(String metroTxt, String metroLoc, String metroId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String first = "next";
    BusinessListApiTask spTask = new BusinessListApiTask(
            BusinessResultListActivity.this);
    try {
        spTask.execute(metroTxt, metroLoc, metroId, first); //Call AsyncTask to fetch data from server
    } catch (Exception e) {
        spTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: make another asynctask and call on button click because in your asynctask you are making adapter=null, that makes append on listview rather than replacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.addAll()` which appends data to the data the adapter already has. The quick-fix is to just drop all data prior to calling `.addAll()` by using [`.clear()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear()).

```
//...
this.businesses.clear();
this.businesses.addAll(businesses);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//...
```

Comment: That seems to help but problem would be, I've to use OnClickListener too and append data on scroll while making previous data still available. How can I achieve that. I have a single AsyncTask to perform all these as data to be returned are same.
How to identify if the call triggered by toolbar search button or onScrollListener or is Default search result(result populated at first when activity is started)??

Comment: Please think through what you want to achieve and make a new SO question regarding that specific problem.

Comment: Thanks, I solved problem (with your answer) by defining static variable and applying condition based on value of that variable.